# Google Drive Links & File Names

Tags: google-apps-script, filenames

I am using google sheets script editor to  get the file names and urls from a folder of files. I have adapted this code (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88769/get-share-link-of-multiple-files-in-google-drive-to-put-in-spreadsheet?answertab=active#tab-top) to print the urls, but I'm not sure how to bring in the file names.

The files are, for example,

A.csv

B.csv

C.csv

And I want to print

Ids Urls

A   https://drive.google.com/file/d/....

B   https://drive.google.com/file/d/....

B   https://drive.google.com/file/d/....

Here is my code

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c1 = s.getRange("B2");
  var c2 = s.getRange("A2")
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("14ZKphLE02f6tdyU7LGEjbEEfrfD89nJM");
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var urls = [], f, str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f = files.next();
    str = '=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
    urls.push([str]);
  }
  s.getRange(c1.getRow(), c1.getColumn(), urls.length).setFormulas(urls);
  var ids = [], f, str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f = files.next();
    str = 'f.getName()';
    ids.push([str])
  }
  s.getRange(c2.getRow(), c2.getColumn(), ids.length).setValues(ids);
}
```

I am getting the error: "The number of rows in the range must be at least 1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you encountered such error is because your array `ids` is empty.
When you use [FileIterator.next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next) to gets the next item in the collection of files, You finished checking all the items in your file from your first while loop. Hence, the second while loop will not be executed anymore. (You can include logs to debug your code. Initially, your `files.hasNext()` will return `false` in your second while loop).

You can actually list the file name and construct your url using your first while loop.

### Sample Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var c1 = s.getRange("B2");
  var c2 = s.getRange("A2")
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("14ZKphLE02f6tdyU7LGEjbEEfrfD89nJM");
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var urls = [], ids = [], f, str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f = files.next();
    str = '=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
    urls.push([str]);
    //ids.push([f.getName()]); //Filename with extensions
    ids.push([f.getName().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")]); //Remove filename extensions
  }

  s.getRange(c1.getRow(), c1.getColumn(), urls.length).setFormulas(urls);
  s.getRange(c2.getRow(), c2.getColumn(), ids.length).setValues(ids);

}
```

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var A = [], f, str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f = files.next();
    str = '=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
    A.push([f.getName(), str]);
  }
  s.getRange(2, 2, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
}
```

Output:

| Filename | Url |
| --- | --- |
| htmlstring.txt | Redacted |
| Testing doPost and doGet | Redacted |
| TestSource | Redacted |
| Doc1 | Redacted |
| Doc2 | Redacted |
| Redacted | Redacted |
| editlog.csv | Redacted |